# How to put "> /dev/null 2>&1" into a variable?

Tags: bash

How I wish it to work.

```
if [ $debug = 0 ]; then
   silent=""
else
   silent='> /dev/null 2>&1'
fi

#some command
wget some.url $silent
```

So in case $debug is set, it becomes

```
wget some.url > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Otherwise if $debug is not set to 1, it becomes

```
wget some.url
```

Storing "> /dev/null 2>&1" in a variable doesn't work. How can I do that?

Comment: BTW, the `-q` option for `wget` provides the exact functionality you seem to be looking for.

Comment: It doesn't work that way for a good reason: Converting data (like variable contents) into syntax (like redirections) is a security nightmare. `eval` forces that to happen -- which is exactly why you shouldn't use `eval`. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048 for more discussion.

Comment: Its not just about wget. I need that quite often. The "wget some.url" is more like a placeholder for "any command".

Answer (score 5):

This could be a good excuse to use a shell function:

```
silent() {
    "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1
}
```

Now you can silence programs by running them with:

```
silent wget some.url
```

If you want to only silence things conditionally, that's easy enough:

```
silent() {
  if [[ $debug ]] ; then
    "$@"
  else
    "$@" &>/dev/null
  fi
}
```

Comment: Use `"$@"`, not `$*`.

Comment: Obligatory reference: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: You could then use `if [ $debug = 0 ]; then maybesilent=""; else maybesilent=silent; fi ... $maybesilent wget some.url`

Comment: @GordonDavisson ...but why would you do that? The `silent` function can check for whether a flag is set perfectly well itself. Using string-splitting to form command lines is, if not outright evil, hard to predict in the corner cases; if someone set `$IFS` to, say, `i` (unusual, but not unheard of -- say, parsing a file with odd delimiters), then `$maybesilent wget some.url` would become `s lent wget some.url` when `maybesilent=silent`.

Answer (score 3):

You need the shell to actually interpret the variable contents as part of the command line, not just as a string to be passed as an argument to the executable.  Check out the [`eval` shell builtin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23111/what-is-the-eval-command-in-bash).

Watch out for security holes!

Comment: Why suggest something dangerous, when you could suggest something safe (function use)?

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different approach, but something like this might work:

```
if [ $debug = 1 ]; then
   exec > /dev/null
fi

#some command
wget some.url
```

It conditionally replaces `stdout` with `/dev/null`.

Comment: Only quibble here is that either `$debug` should be in double quotes or `[[ ]]` should be used in place of `[ ]` to prevent the test from behaving badly when it parses to anything other than a single token when going through string-splitting or glob expansion.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Agreed. I deliberately didn't change anything except the redirection but that's certainly the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use `eval`:

```
eval wget some.url $silent
```

`eval` causes the arguments to be reintepreted as a shell command, rather than as arguments to the program being called.

Be careful; don't run `eval` on unknown or external input, or you will expose yourself to a big security hole.

Comment: Use of `eval` is exceedingly dangerous. Try operating on a file with `$(rm -rf /)` in the name...

Comment: In a case where the arguments are tightly controlled and do not incorporate external input (as in this case), its use is safe.

Comment: Part of the point of Stack Overflow is to be a base of knowledge. Having answers in a knowledge base which create risk when used outside of a very narrow window of safety is making that a minefield. Moreover -- you never know how the code you write is going to get changed or updated in the future; conditions that were true when it was first drafted may not always hold for the lifespan.